# Update unpivoted table with one to many relation

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Imagin you have a main table like that

```
DECLARE @ExistentData TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1000,1), [Row] INT, [Col] INT, Val NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @ExistentData([Row], [Col], Val)
VALUES 
(1,10,'Value 1'),
(1,11,'Value 2'),
(1,12,'Value 3.1'),
(1,12,'Value 3.2')

ID          Row         Col         Val
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
1000        1           10          Value 1
1001        1           11          Value 2
1002        1           12          Value 3.1
1003        1           12          Value 3.2
```

Then you want to update above table with data below

```
DECLARE @NewDataToUpdateExistent TABLE ([Row] int, [Col] int, Val nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO @NewDataToUpdateExistent([Row], [Col], Val)
VALUES 
(1,10,'Updated Value 1'),
/*(1,11,'Deleted Value 2'),*/
(1,12,'Updated Value 3.1'),
(1,12,'Updated 3.2'),
(1,12,'New Value 3.3')

Row         Col         Val
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           10          Updated Value 1
1           12          Updated Value 3.1
1           12          Updated 3.2
1           12          New Value 3.3
```

I want to do some performant update (without using cursors or other ugly iteration stuff)
resulting in the following final data on main table (@ExistentData)

```
ID          Row         Col         Val
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
1000        1           10          Updated Value 1
1002        1           12          Updated Value 3.1
1003        1           12          Updated Value 3.2
1004        1           12          New Value 3.3
```

Deleting all related data and insert again (atm I'm doing this ) is not an option cause is an expansive operation regarding FK with other tables and index/statics management.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use an ordinary `UPDATE`?  It looks like a simple join on two columns.  Have you tested this and found it to be too slow?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades the main problem with ordinary `UPDATE` is one to many relation. For the same [Row] and [Col] I might have more than one [Val] (e.g Row 1, Col 12). Maybe is simplier than I thought but I'm stuck with this.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice that `Col` wasn't unique in the second example.  I guess I need more coffee.  So by what criteria do you want #1002 and #1003 changed to 3.1 and 3.2 respectively, rather than 3.2 and 3.1, or 3.3?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades no problem! Regarding your question I don't care about that order. Now I'm trying something using `ROW_NUMBER` in a way as a colleague suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ExistentData 
TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1000,1), [Row] INT, [Col] INT, Val NVARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @ExistentData([Row], [Col], Val)
VALUES 
(1,10,'Value 1'),
(1,11,'Value 2'),
(1,12,'Value 3.1'),
(1,12,'Value 3.2')
select * from @ExistentData    

DECLARE @NewDataToUpdateExistent TABLE ([Row] int, [Col] int, Val nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO @NewDataToUpdateExistent([Row], [Col], Val)
VALUES 
(1,10,'Updated Value 1'),
/*(1,11,'Deleted Value 2'),*/
(1,12,'Updated Value 3.1'),
(1,12,'Updated 3.2'),
(1,12,'New Value 3.3')
select * from @NewDataToUpdateExistent
```

With `ROW_NUMBER` you do the trick

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (ID INT, [Row] INT, [Col] INT, Val NVARCHAR(50), [RowNumb] INT);
INSERT INTO @A (ID, [Row], [Col], Val, RowNumb)
SELECT A.ID, A.[Row], A.Col, A.Val,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY A.[Row], A.[Col] ORDER BY A.[Row], A.[Col] DESC) AS RowNumb
FROM @ExistentData A
;

DECLARE @B TABLE ([Row] INT, [Col] INT, Val NVARCHAR(50), [RowNumb] INT);
INSERT INTO @B ([Row], [Col], Val, RowNumb)
SELECT B.[Row], B.Col, B.Val,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY B.[Row], B.[Col] ORDER BY B.[Row], B.[Col] DESC) AS RowNumb
FROM @NewDataToUpdateExistent B
;
```

Now just joining tables in the following way you get the expected result

```
--Delete
DELETE ed
FROM @A a
LEFT OUTER JOIN @B b 
    ON  a.[Row] = b.[Row] AND a.[Col] = b.[Col] 
    AND a.[RowNumb] = b.[RowNumb]
INNER JOIN @ExistentData ed ON a.ID = ed.ID
WHERE b.[Row] IS NULL

--Update
UPDATE ed
SET ed.Val = B.Val
FROM @A a
INNER JOIN @B b 
    ON  a.[Row] = b.[Row] AND a.[Col] = b.[Col] 
    AND a.[RowNumb] = b.[RowNumb]
INNER JOIN @ExistentData ed ON a.ID = ed.ID

--INSERT
INSERT INTO @ExistentData([Row], [Col], Val)
SELECT b.[Row], b.[Col], b.Val
FROM @B b
LEFT OUTER JOIN @A a 
    ON a.[Row] = b.[Row] AND a.[Col] = b.[Col] 
    AND a.[RowNumb] = b.[RowNumb]
WHERE A.[Row] IS NULL
```

> SELECT * FROM @ExistentData
>       ORDER BY id

```
ID          Row         Col         Val
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
1000        1           10          Updated Value 1
1002        1           12          Updated Value 3.1
1003        1           12          Updated Value 3.2
1004        1           12          New Value 3.3
```